# How can I modify the core api in java ？

Tags: java, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm, byte-buddy

for example：I want to change  LocalDateTime.now() return result in non-production enviroment，
I am trying to invoke the following code，but error occors：

```java
   @Test
    public void test3() {
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now());
        Instrumentation instrumentation = ByteBuddyAgent.install();
        Class<?>[] cls = instrumentation.getAllLoadedClasses();
        for (Class<?> cl : cls) {
            if ("java.time.LocalDateTime".equals(cl.getName())) {
                try {
                    LocalDateTime mockData = LocalDateTime.of(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                    byte[] bytes = new ByteBuddy()
                            .redefine(LocalDateTime.class)
                            .method(ElementMatchers.named("now").and(ElementMatchers.takesNoArguments()))
                            .intercept(FixedValue.value(mockData))
                            .make()
                            .getBytes();
                    ClassDefinition classDefinition = new ClassDefinition(cl, bytes);
                    instrumentation.redefineClasses(classDefinition);
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now());
    }
```

2024-03-03T15:33:59.291699
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: class redefinition failed: attempted to change the schema (add/remove fields)
at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.redefineClasses0(Native Method)
at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.redefineClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:195)
at com.yi.component.test.agent.bytecode.ByteBuddyTest.test3(ByteBuddyTest.java:76)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)

I want to change  LocalDateTime.now() return result in non-production enviroment

Comment: _Why_ do you want to change the method? What is it you're actually trying to do for which you think you need to do this?

Comment: The right way to have a different "current time" in non-production environments (for example, for testing what will happen at some future date) is _never_ to use `LocalDateTime.now()`, but always `LocalDateTime.now(Clock clock)` instead, and inject a suitable `Clock` implementation into any class that needs the current time.  Are you sure that _"How can I modify the core api in Java"_ is the question you actually want to ask?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem: In a non-production environment, another option is to set the system clock to any time you want.  (e.g. inside a VM, but outside the JVM.)  Or perhaps with LD_PRELOAD with a library that intercepts libc function calls by the JVM, so `clock_gettime` will return different times. That would let LocalDateTime stuff be different from the mod times on files your program writes.

Comment: purpose ： change the implementation of get system time in non-prd-env，and the developer do nothing，and can not change the system clock.

Comment: @PeterCordes - Well yea ... but that potentially effects the entire system.  It will break some things (e.g. those that depend on clocks being in sync with other machines), and make other things behave in undesirable ways; e.g. timestamps in log messages for the entire environment.

Comment: change the implementation of get system time in non-prd-env，and the developer do nothing，and can not change the system clock.

Comment: @yicai.liu but _why_? Are you actually just trying to fix time in tests? If so, dependency injection is the correct solution to that as already hinted at. If that's not what you're trying to do, please clarify.

Comment: for tester-engineer testing the schedule task without lots of business code modify

Comment: is this eventually a use case for some mocking framework like Mockito?

Comment: You don't even need a mocking framework to do that. I'm currently travelling, but I'll write an answer shortly.

Comment: searching the error message gives the following [results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=class+redefinition+failed%3A+attempted+to+change+the+schema) on this site! See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48117384/85421): "**FixedValue** can only be used with Strings, Class object, primitive types and their wrappers. ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you actually want to do is be able to control the time in your tests, which is very sensible.

The simpler way to go about this is using dependency injection: instead of having the class you want to test know about the system clock, pass in the clock so that you can vary the clock you use for testing and for production.

As an example, let's say you need to compute fines for loaned items that are overdue (e.g. for a library or something). Your business rules may be:

- The fine is 1 for every day the item is overdue
- The fine is 0 if the item is not overdue

Note that I'm using recent tools: JUnit 5 and records were introduced in Java 14 (I'm on 21).

Here is a definition of a loaned item:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public record LoanedItem(String description, LocalDate dueOn) {}
```

and test cases expressing the behaviour:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.time.Clock;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class FineCalculatorTest {
    @Test
    public void the_fine_is_1_for_every_day_the_item_is_overdue() {
        LocalDate dueOn = LocalDate.of(2024, 2, 1);
        LoanedItem loanedItem = new LoanedItem("Lawnmower", dueOn);

        int daysOverdue = 2;
        LocalDate today = dueOn.plusDays(daysOverdue);
        Clock clock = Clock.fixed(today.atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC), ZoneOffset.UTC);

        FineCalculator fineCalculator = new FineCalculator(clock);

        long fine = fineCalculator.fineFor(loanedItem);

        assertEquals(2, fine);
    }

    @Test
    public void the_fine_is_0_if_the_item_is_not_overdue() {
        LocalDate dueOn = LocalDate.of(2024, 2, 1);
        LoanedItem loanedItem = new LoanedItem("Lawnmower", dueOn);

        LocalDate today = dueOn.minusDays(7);
        Clock clock = Clock.fixed(today.atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC), ZoneOffset.UTC);

        FineCalculator fineCalculator = new FineCalculator(clock);

        long fine = fineCalculator.fineFor(loanedItem);

        assertEquals(0, fine);
    }
}
```

The key thing to note is that `FineCalculator` takes, as a constructor parameter, an instance of `java.time.Clock`.

`Clock.fixed` creates a `Clock` whose time is fixed at what you give it. In the first test, then, I create a clock that's fixed at two days after the item's due date:

```
int daysOverdue = 2;
LocalDate today = dueOn.plusDays(daysOverdue);
Clock clock = Clock.fixed(today.atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC), ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

so we expect a fine of 2.

The second case is similar: I pass a clock that's fixed at 7 days before the due date, so we expect a fine of 0.

The implementation of `FineCalculator` then uses the clock to work out what today is and calculate the fine:

```
import java.time.Clock;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class FineCalculator {
    private Clock clock;

    public FineCalculator(Clock clock) {
        this.clock = clock;
    }

    public long fineFor(LoanedItem loanedItem) {
        LocalDate today = clock.instant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate();

        long daysOverdue = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(loanedItem.dueOn(), today);

        if (daysOverdue < 0) {
            daysOverdue = 0;
        }

        long fine = 1 * daysOverdue;

        return fine;
    }
}
```

When you create the `FineCalculator` in the production code, you'd pass the system clock. Here's a sample `main`:

```
import java.time.Clock;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LoanedItem item = new LoanedItem("Screwdriver", LocalDate.of(2024, 9, 1));

        Clock clock = Clock.system(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        FineCalculator fineCalculator = new FineCalculator(clock);

        System.out.println("Loaned item: " + item);
        System.out.println("Fine is: " + fineCalculator.fineFor(item));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution found :

solution 1:

```
git clone https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime.git
make
sudo make install

faketime '@2007-01-01 00:00:00' java -jar xxx.jar
```

solution 2:

```
Use linux 5.6+ kernel feature - time namespace 
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/39163
https://securitylabs.datadoghq.com/articles/container-security-fundamentals-part-2/#time-namespace
```